Composer update is ok but composer outdated shows many items
I'm running the latest version of Magento 2.4.7-p2.
If I run composer update this is what is shown:
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package laminas/laminas-crypt is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package sebastian/phpcpd is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating autoload files
148 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
No security vulnerability advisories found.

but if I run composer outdated this is the output:
Color legend:
- patch or minor release available - update recommended
- major release available - update possible

Direct dependencies required in composer.json:
allure-framework/allure-phpunit               2.1.0   3.0.1  Allure PHPUnit integration
magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 4.7.2   4.8.2  Magento2 Functional Testing Framework
phpunit/phpunit                               9.6.20  11.3.1 The PHP Unit Testing framework.
sebastian/phpcpd                              6.0.3   6.0.3  Copy/Paste Detector (CPD) for PHP code.
Package sebastian/phpcpd is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
symfony/finder                                6.4.11  7.1.4  Finds files and directories via an intuitive fluent interface

Transitive dependencies not required in composer.json:
bacon/bacon-qr-code                           2.0.8   3.0.0  BaconQrCode is a QR code generator for PHP.
braintree/braintree_php                       6.13.0  6.19.0 Braintree PHP Client Library
codeception/module-webdriver                  3.2.2   4.0.2  WebDriver module for Codeception
colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract    1.5.5   2.0.0  A Redis-based session handler with optimistic locking
composer/composer                             2.7.7   2.7.8  Composer helps you declare, manage and install dependencies of PHP projects. It ensures you have the right stack everywhere.
elasticsearch/elasticsearch                   7.17.2  8.15.0 PHP Client for Elasticsearch
endroid/qr-code                               4.8.5   5.0.9  Endroid QR Code
ezimuel/guzzlestreams                         3.1.0   4.0.0  Fork of guzzle/streams (abandoned) to be used with elasticsearch-php
justinrainbow/json-schema                     5.3.0   6.0.0  A library to validate a json schema.
laminas/laminas-crypt                         3.12.0  4.0.0  Strong cryptography tools and password hashing
Package laminas/laminas-crypt is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
laminas/laminas-servicemanager                3.22.1  4.2.0  Factory-Driven Dependency Injection Container
league/flysystem                              2.5.0   3.28.0 File storage abstraction for PHP
league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3                    2.5.0   3.28.0 AWS S3 filesystem adapter for Flysystem.
monolog/monolog                               2.9.3   3.7.0  Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services
php-amqplib/php-amqplib                       3.2.0   3.7.0  Formerly videlalvaro/php-amqplib.  This library is a pure PHP implementation of the AMQP protocol. It's been tested against RabbitMQ.
phpunit/php-code-coverage                     9.2.32  11.0.6 Library that provides collection, processing, and rendering functionality for PHP code coverage information.
phpunit/php-file-iterator                     3.0.6   5.1.0  FilterIterator implementation that filters files based on a list of suffixes.
phpunit/php-invoker                           3.1.1   5.0.1  Invoke callables with a timeout
phpunit/php-text-template                     2.0.4   4.0.1  Simple template engine.
phpunit/php-timer                             5.0.3   7.0.1  Utility class for timing
psr/container                                 1.1.2   2.0.2  Common Container Interface (PHP FIG PSR-11)
react/promise                                 2.11.0  3.2.0  A lightweight implementation of CommonJS Promises/A for PHP
rector/rector                                 0.17.13 1.2.4  Instant Upgrade and Automated Refactoring of any PHP code
sebastian/cli-parser                          1.0.2   3.0.2  Library for parsing CLI options
sebastian/code-unit                           1.0.8   3.0.1  Collection of value objects that represent the PHP code units
sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup            2.0.3   4.0.1  Looks up which function or method a line of code belongs to
sebastian/comparator                          4.0.8   6.0.2  Provides the functionality to compare PHP values for equality
sebastian/complexity                          2.0.3   4.0.1  Library for calculating the complexity of PHP code units
sebastian/diff                                4.0.6   6.0.2  Diff implementation
sebastian/environment                         5.1.5   7.2.0  Provides functionality to handle HHVM/PHP environments
sebastian/exporter                            4.0.6   6.1.3  Provides the functionality to export PHP variables for visualization
sebastian/global-state                        5.0.7   7.0.2  Snapshotting of global state
sebastian/lines-of-code                       1.0.4   3.0.1  Library for counting the lines of code in PHP source code
sebastian/object-enumerator                   4.0.4   6.0.1  Traverses array structures and object graphs to enumerate all referenced objects
sebastian/object-reflector                    2.0.4   4.0.1  Allows reflection of object attributes, including inherited and non-public ones
sebastian/recursion-context                   4.0.5   6.0.2  Provides functionality to recursively process PHP variables
sebastian/type                                3.2.1   5.0.1  Collection of value objects that represent the types of the PHP type system
sebastian/version                             3.0.2   5.0.1  Library that helps with managing the version number of Git-hosted PHP projects
symfony/config                                6.4.8   7.1.1  Helps you find, load, combine, autofill and validate configuration values of any kind
symfony/console                               6.4.11  7.1.4  Eases the creation of beautiful and testable command line interfaces
symfony/css-selector                          6.4.8   7.1.1  Converts CSS selectors to XPath expressions
symfony/dependency-injection                  6.4.11  7.1.4  Allows you to standardize and centralize the way objects are constructed in your application
symfony/dotenv                                6.4.10  7.1.3  Registers environment variables from a .env file
symfony/event-dispatcher                      6.4.8   7.1.1  Provides tools that allow your application components to communicate with each other by dispatching events and listening to them
symfony/filesystem                            6.4.9   7.1.2  Provides basic utilities for the filesystem
symfony/http-foundation                       6.4.10  7.1.3  Defines an object-oriented layer for the HTTP specification
symfony/intl                                  6.4.8   7.1.1  Provides access to the localization data of the ICU library
symfony/mime                                  6.4.11  7.1.4  Allows manipulating MIME messages
symfony/process                               6.4.8   7.1.3  Executes commands in sub-processes
symfony/stopwatch                             6.4.8   7.1.1  Provides a way to profile code
symfony/string                                6.4.11  7.1.4  Provides an object-oriented API to strings and deals with bytes, UTF-8 code points and grapheme clusters in a unified way
symfony/var-exporter                          6.4.9   7.1.2  Allows exporting any serializable PHP data structure to plain PHP code
web-token/jwt-framework                       3.4.6   4.0.1  JSON Object Signing and Encryption library for PHP and Symfony Bundle.
wikimedia/less.php                            3.2.1   5.1.1  PHP port of the LESS processor

Should I upgrade all the dependencies showed? How?

After the update, first verify if the module version has been upgraded ?
If not, rename your "composer.lock" file and rerun the composer update command. Then, check if your composer is functioning correctly or not

I renamed the composer.lock to composer.lock.bak then I run composer update again and it just recreated the same composer.lock file with the same content. If I run composer outdated again it shows the same output.
